# ArrayAdapter type cast from android docs example

Tags: android

I am trying to create a list of strings from my arrays.xml file, as found in the android docs too. This is what they use:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.colors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

eclipse is warning that the ArrayAdapter instance is a raw type. Should it really be:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ...;
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi
It's always better to leave type checking to java compiler, so it would be better to declare your adapter as 
`ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>` It probably doesn't change anything in your code, especially when you are sure that you are not going to put anything else but strings to your adapter. But it's definately a good practice to use generics  to avoid runtime exceptions.
Regards!